# Which would be faster....many insert single value statements or an insert statament with many values?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Which will be faster in execution among the following cases? (It is required to decide appropriate approach in my project)

```
insert into table values (v1, v2, v3);
```

or

```
insert into table1 value (v1)
insert into table1 value (v2)
insert into table1 value (v3)
```

what are your opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not my opinion; but from experience doing something in one query rather than multiple ones to achieve the same thing is always faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using batching properly it shouldn't make a huge difference.  The first would be faster however.

Answer (score 0):

The approach 1 would be faster than the approach 2 , because of following reasons

1.Less network calls
2.Less Compilation/Parsing/Explain Plan/ in DB

Regards
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong. If you're trying to insert multiple rows with one insert, your query would look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (v1), (v2), (v3)
```

And executing with one query is always faster than multiple queries (that do the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

The (v1, v2, v3) version will be faster, but be careful how best to do this in your driver.  In Java, you'd use a simple `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)` PreparedStatement, and use addBatch() to combine them into a single larger statement that is executed with executeBatch().

See section 3.4:
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/

You would also need to enable the `rewriteBatchedStatements` property in the Connector/J driver:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

`LOAD DATA INFILE` will be faster still if that works for your application.